# File routing on symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig

I was reviewing the symfony 3.4 routing page. I have a misunderstanding if anyone can help me. So say you have the following: 
In Your controller:

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Matches /blog exactly
     *
     * @Route("/blog", name="blog_list")
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And in your routing.yml:

```
blog_list:
    path:     /blog
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Blog:list }
```

Would you be able to delete the route annotation above the function. Because now the routing is being handled by the routing.yml?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must choose one of this methods to set route for current url "/blog"

Comment: But if I delete the '@' annotation it won't be to access the page... So how is what you're saying true...?

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony Routing can be declare using YAML, XML, PHP or annotation. It is recommended you stick with only one but you can use multiple approaches in a single project.

Official doc for routing [Symfony Routing](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing.html)

and the answer to your question is, I would say yes you could delete the annotation. 
Because now the routing is being handled by the routing.yml

for the big project, I prefer YML routing.